# Loading binary only onto Iphone for testing

Tags: iphone

Can you load a binary file onto an iPhone using xcode? We are an OEM that needs to QA test an application from a third party developer that owns the source code. They only provide us with the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your iPhone is Jailbroken, just create an `.app` folder, put the binary in, fill in the necessary Info.plist entries and throw it into `/Applications`.
2. You could create a dummy project, compile it, then find the generated .app bundle, replace the executable inside, then run the dummy app.
3. Or just ask the 3rd party dev to create an Ad Hoc distribution. Much better than the 2 methods above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also send the 3rd party Dev the UDIDs from your iPod / iPhone units and they can create a provisioning profile for you so you can install the app on your test devices.  No ad-hoc distribution needed.